JPA repository query that returns all rows with a nth-to-nth relation
I have a table that looks like this:



id
A
B




1
A1
B1


2
A1
B2


3
A2
B2


4
A2
B3



Then I have a list of items for which I want to find the corresponding database rows. For instance, i might have (in the form of JSON)
[
 {
  "A": "A1",
  "B": "B4",
 },
 {
  "A": "A1",
  "B": "B2",
 }
]

This should now return the rows with Id 2. These items for which I want to query the database can be thousands.
Naively, I came up with
findAllByAinAndBIn(List<A> aValues, List<B> bValues) 
but that doesn't work since this doesn't find the rows with a nth element to nth element comparison. What should i do instead?

The simplest approach would be to create a concatenated list of ids and then compare them against the database using a JPQL query.
1. Create a concatenated list of the ids
 List<String> matches = jsonArrayList.parallelStream().map(e -> e.getA() + ":" + movie.getB()).toList();

2. Create a JPQL query to compare the concatenated ids against the database
@Query("select m from Entity m where CONCAT(m.a, ':', m.b) IN (:matches)")
List<Entity> findAllMatchingRows(@Param("matches") List<String> matches);


This approach has a fundamental defect: if : is permitted in a value, then incorrect rows might be returned; e.g., row(id, A, B) with values [1, 'A1:', 'B1'] would match search criteria [{"A": "A1", "B": ":B1"}] even though neither search term exists in the row. There is also the problem that the search conditions aren't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable} without creating a functional index with a corresponding search expression.

I would still stick to this approach of using derived queries as it would be easier to understand for anyone who works on this code in future. Only if there is a performance issue in the long run, you may consider querying a view instead of the direct table.

Wether or not an approach is more readable is irrelevant if it isn't guaranteed to produce correct results. The concatenation approach might be acceptable if the searched columns are constrained to exclude :. An engineered solution should address the possible, not just the probable.

The following query demonstrates an approach using a JSON array of search terms:
WITH
  entity(id, a, b) AS (
    VALUES
      (1, 'A1', 'B1'),
      (2, 'A1', 'B2'),
      (3, 'A2', 'B2'),
      (4, 'A2', 'B3')
  )
SELECT
  entity.*
FROM
  entity JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS('[{"A": "A1", "B": "B4"}, {"A": "A1", "B": "B2"}]'::JSONB) j(criteria)
  ON (entity.a, entity.b) = (j.criteria ->> 'A', j.criteria ->> 'B');

The following is an example using a JPA native query:
@Query(value = "SELECT entity.* FROM entity JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(:criteria) j(criteria) ON (entity.a, entity.b) = (j.criteria ->> 'A', j.criteria ->> 'B')", nativeQuery = true)
Entity findEntityByAAndB(@Param("criteria") String "[{\"A\": \"A1\", \"B\": \"B4\"}, {\"A\": \"A1\", \"B\": \"B2\"}]");

